Parameter passed with value of 0 from Codeigniter Controller to View, Comes through blank
I'm converting a large project from Codeigniter 3 to Codeigniter 4.  I'm having strange behavior that didn't happen in CI3 but is now happening in CI4.  I have a controller with the following:
public function info($projectid=-1,$datasetid=-1,$doImportCk=1){
    $data['doImportCk'] = $doImportCk;
    $this->common->render_page($basics,'manage/dataset/info',$data);
}

Render page just echos the views like this:
     public function render_page($basics,$viewname,$data=array()){                 
        
        echo view('template/top',$basics);
        echo view('template/header');
        echo view('template/leftnav');
        
        if(is_array($viewname)){
            foreach ($viewname as $view){
                echo view($view,$data);
            }
        }
        else{
            echo view($viewname,$data);
        }

        echo view('template/footer');
     }

Now, when the view renders, I get an error in the console that shows $doImportCk is blank. The code in the view looks like this:
var doImportCk=<?php echo $doImportCk;?>;


How do I get that value to come through as 0 and not null/blank?  It used to work in CI3...

The issue was a slash at the end of the route.  In CI3 we didn't have required routes, and when I made the route for this page I left a trailing slash at the end.  Example is this:
$routes->get('manage/project/(:num)/dataset/(:num)/(:any)','Manage\Dataset::$3/$1/$2/');

had to be changed to:
$routes->get('manage/project/(:num)/dataset/(:num)/(:any)','Manage\Dataset::$3/$1/$2');

